# calling controller function from javascript in ruby on rails using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i have function get_rule(rulename) in controller/team/index_controller.rb which is returnig a map and i have javascript from which i want to call this function . Right now i am doing an ajax call from this script

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<%= Rails.configuration.url_prefix %>/team/index/get_rule_attribute_values",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(){
            console.log("success");

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown){
            var requestResponse = {
            httpStatus: jqXHR.status,
             error:jqXHR.statusText,

         };

          console.log("requestResponse");

         // Notify the user so he might not wonder.
          alert('Something went wrong, Please try again');


               // Report it back for fixing it
         // Only for debuggify users
        var ajaxErrors = debuggify.Logger.get('ajax_errors');
        ajaxErrors.attach(requestResponse);
        ajaxErrors.error('Caught ajax error');

          }
        });
```

my getrule func

```
def getrule(rule_attribute_name)
    # rule_attr_value = RuleAttribute.get_rule_attributes rule_attribute_name
    # rule_attribute_values_hash = JSON.parse(rule_attr_value)
    # rule_attr_values = rule_attribute_values_hash["rule_attribute_values"]
    # rule_attribute_values = Hash.new
    # rule_attr_values.each do |value|
      # rule_attribute_values.store(value["internal_name"],value["display_name"])
    # end
    respond_to do |format|
            format.json {render :json =>{:error => false, :message => "test"}}
     return rule_attribute_values 
end
```

please provide me some suggesstion or code  so that i can make a call . i spent whole day on single but don't want to waste more time on this.And i want the map returning from controller function in a variable i.e. i want response of ajax into a variable

Comment: please check your routes, for example running "rake routes" on command line or browse http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes  I think your route can be shorter like ends with: ...team/index/get_rule  + pass your attributes in jQuery.ajax's data variable. More info: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i think problem is in query not in routes . provide me some method to do so

Comment: no.. It's probably in the routes